# Cannot enter comment text after rotating app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

In the Android app, if I start writing a comment, then change the screen orientation (usually because I'm commenting while running for a bus), I can no longer continue typing in the comment box. I can focus on the box, and bring the keyboard up, but typing does nothing.

Refreshing the question doesn't fix it either. The only way around it is to completely exit the question, and go back in.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're right. Evidently I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: All good, dupes are useful to find things easily. :)